# Find maxpairs without using loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, math

[image]

Hey guys, any solutions without using loop, if n = 10^5, loop is too slow, I'm searching for another solutions
My code is below and does not take duplicate value, so that it's not correct at all

```
def maxPairs():
minDiff = 3
pairs = []
skillLevel = []
for i in range(pow(10,5)):
    skillLevel.append(random.randint(1, 5))
print(skillLevel)
skillLevel.sort()
for x in skillLevel:
    for y in skillLevel:
        if abs(x-y) >= minDiff and [x,y] not in pairs and [y,x] not in pairs:
            pairs.append([x,y])
            skillLevel.remove(x)
            skillLevel.remove(y)
            break

return len(pairs)


start = time.time()
print(maxPairs())
print(f"{time.time()-start}")
```

Comment: Any solution will use loop. Perhaps you are using quadratic (or worse) algorithm, but you have not shown your tryouts.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to put mine. The problem is I want to optimize the running time with large number

Comment: so if using 2 loops to query  10^5 value of the list like above seems awful

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this optimized solution in typescript using a hash table:

```
export function maxPairsOptimized(ratings: number[], minDiff: number){
    const mapPairs = new Map<number, [number, number]>();
    ratings.forEach(rating => {
        const result = rating - minDiff;
        if(result > 0 && !mapPairs.has(result)) {
            mapPairs.set(result, [result, rating]);
        }
    }); 
    if(mapPairs.size === 0) return [];
    return Array.from(mapPairs.values());
}
```